# How to print list of dict in django?

Tags: python, django

I have list of dict named menu_dict_list:

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 0, 0), 
  'Popcorn': 5, 'Coke': 5, 'Chips': 0, 'Burger': 3}, 
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 10, 0, 0), 
  'Popcorn': 4, 'Coke': 4, 'Chips': 0, 'Burger': 0}]
```

I had followed this approach:

```
**{% for menu_dict in menu_dict_list %}
 <tr> 
 {% for key,value in menu_dict %}
 <td>{{value}}</td>
 {% endfor %}
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}**
```

How to print it in django? But its not working good. Thanks in advance

Comment: Remember that iterating over a `dict` produces just the keys. `dict.items()`/`dict.iteritems()` produces the `key, value` pairs. So that's what you have to use in the view. And if you only want the values, use `dict.values`/`dict.itervalues`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `.items` method of the dict:

```
{% for menu_dict in menu_dict_list %}
        <tr>
                {% for key,value in menu_dict.items %}
                        <td>{{value}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: ho sorry... I'm used to write iteritems... you're right... I thought you used "values" as it's the only used value in the for tag...

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is to iterate on the dictionary, look here:

```
<ul>
{% for key,value in menu_dict.iteritems %}
    <li><b>{{ key }}:</b> {{ value }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And just in case you want to make a beautiful table with this, note that dictionary are not ordered so, you may want to use django SortedDict or a list of list of 2entries tuples.